# "Волос", "яйцо" и т.д.

Tags: грамотная-речь

Говоря о предмете во множественном числе, порой люди употребляют форму единственного, например "у меня густой волос". Часто это звучит о товаре в магазине: "пришло яйцо" и т.д.
Насколько это имеет право на существование?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Имеет. Сравните - "торговля рыбой". Ясно, что не одной рыбиной.

Это проявление так называемой грамматической собирательности, тут единственным числом называют не просто "много" объектов, но некоторую физическую или смысловую группу.
Вполне допустимо в разговорной и профессиональной речи. 
В общелитературной - надо смотреть по контексту, думаю, в большинстве случаев тоже допустимо.

Comment: Не могу согласиться с правильностью фразы "у меня густой волос". Помню с детскихлет, что "волос" означает только один волосок. В указанной фразе следует употреблять форму множественного числа. Думаю, подобного типа выражения имеют индивидуальное правописание, так же как родительный падеж множественного числа ряда слов: осетин, но узбеков; грузин, но казахов

Comment: Ну конкретная фраза действительно заставляет усомниться. Но это уже на любителя. "Густой Волос" - это скорее товар, а не принадлежность головы.

Answer (score 0):

Действительно нельзя сказать "у меня густой волос", а то придется себя с животным тогда отождествить :))) Приведу 2-е и 3-е значения слова "волос" из "Грамоты":

**2**. только мн.: волосы, волос.
Растительный покров из таких образований на голове человека. Прямые, курчавые, волнистые волосы. Русые, каштановые, белокурые, седые волосы. Причесать, заколоть, подстричь, накрутить (на бигуди) волосы. Рвать на себе волосы
(о состоянии крайней досады). * Снявши голову, по волосам не плачут (Посл.). 
**3**. собир.
Растительность на теле животного, употребляемая как материал. Конский в. Тюфяк набит волосом.*